# How do I get a list with all the subscribers of my YouTube Channel?

Tags: youtube, youtube-studio

I have a YouTube channel and tried to find my subscribers at the following link:

https://www.youtube.com/subscribers

I can see the total number of subscribers, but I can not access all the names of people.

**"Only subscribers who share their signatures are publicly displayed"**

How do I get a list with all the subscribers of my channel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Short answer

According to the related Youtube help article, only under certain cases it's possible to get the list of all channel subscribers.

## From [See your YouTube Subscribers List](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7280745?hl=en)

> **What subscribers are on the Subscribers List**
>
> - The Subscribers List shows subscribers who have set their subscriptions to public.
> - Subscribers who have their subscriptions set to private don't show in a your  Subscribers List, even if the account is subscribed to your channel.
> - Suspended accounts and subscribers that are identified as spam do not count towards your total number of subscribers and don't show in
>     your Subscribers List.
> - If you have over 1,000 subscribers, your Subscribers List may not show all of your subscribers.
>
> **View your list of public subscribers**
>
> 1. Sign in to YouTube.
> 2. Go to your Subscribers List by clicking Creator Studio > Community > Subscribers.
> 3. You can see your total number of subscribers at the top of the page. The list shows only subscribers who have chosen to share their
>      subscriptions publicly.
> 4. You can sort the list by Most recent or Most popular using the drop-down menu in the top right.

Comment: Then, unfortunately, it is not possible to get a list with the name of all subscribers.

Comment: @LCarvalho: Even if all channel subscribers set their subscriptions to public, could be that you will not be able to get a complete list.

Comment: Maybe it's the privacy policy